# How to add a CSS class to an element with React function components

Tags: reactjs, function, react-hooks, components

i would like to know how can i add a CSS class to an element which has no any CSS classes.I am looking React Functional component solution with Hooks. Here i want to add class to  tag and i don't need to add ${myclass} in advance. That means  tag should be without any attributes before we execute the addclass functionality. I tried the following method and needs to get a best practice on it. Thanks in advance!

```
function Trial(){
  const [myclass, changeclass] = useState("");
  const addclass=()=>{
  changeclass(`active`)
  }  
  return(
    <div>
      <h1 className={` ${myclass}`}>Hi</h1>
      <button onClick={addclass}>Click it</button>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Looking good!  I would rename the addClass function since it's not adding class it's more replaceClass or editClass since it's overwrite the class

Comment: @GiladTamam, actually i already added a class because react need a default state there. Actually i don't need a class preadded in it. I need a blank element like this <h1> and the class needs added only after the function invokes. I hope this make sense.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add an id and then manipulate the element in the DOM by `queryselector`

in the element you want to change its className

```
 <h1 className={`${myclass}`} id = "change-class">Hi</h1>
```

and then in the function

```
  const addclass=()=>{
      document.querySelector("#change-class").classList.add('new-class-name');
  }
```

so the whole code would look like this

```
function Trial(){
 const addclass=()=>{
      document.querySelector("#change-class").classList.add('new-class-name');
  }  

return(
    <div>
     <h1 className={`${myclass}`} id = "change-class" >Hi</h1>
      <button onClick={addclass}>Click it</button>
    </div>
  )
}
```

For more info check [here](https://intellipaat.com/community/21064/how-to-change-an-elements-class-with-javascript) and [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_queryselector.asp)

Comment: it works and your idea is good. But let me know is it a best practice to do functionalities without React Hooks. Let me know.

Comment: Hooks are like ordinary functions and there is no difference between hooks and functions, and `querySelector` is a function as well, therefor it doesn't matter wether you use hooks or not.

Comment: Actually, there is no need to add an ID. It will work in the following method also.
```function Trial(){
  const addclass=()=>{
       document.querySelector("h1").classList.add('new-class-name');
   }  
 
 return(
     <div>
      <h1>Hi</h1>
       <button onClick={addclass}>Click it</button>
     </div>
   )
 }```

Comment: @RenJitsm Yes, but what if we add another `h1` and then we decide to add class to the new one? We still can do it but it makes the code messy and it works fine for beginner who don't want to make big project  there is no need for that when we can add `id` so i belive best practice is `id`s

Comment: Also if my answer was helpful, please mark it as accepted and vote it up so that future visitors will use it

Comment: Okay Yahya, i'm doing it. Thank You for your effort!

Comment: I'm glad to help.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [useRef()](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref) hook for this:

```
function Trial(){
  const ref = useRef(null);
  const addclass=()=>{
     const h1 = ref.current; // corresponding DOM node
     h1.className = "active";
  }  
  return(
    <div>
      <h1 ref={ref} className="">Hi</h1>
      <button onClick={addclass}>Click it</button>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your attempt of help. But i got other solution based on ordinary functon inside component

Comment: You're welcome. Both solutions would work and it is entirely subjective which one you prefer. But for me, this solution is more inclined towards react way of doing things.

Comment: @RenJitsm, when you ask a question and then solve it, it's helpful to share the specifics of the solution you used so others who get your question in search results can get the answer as well.